# Placement of air pressure tank with respect to outlet of the water pressure pump

Tags: water, pump, pressure

Does the pressure tank need to be above the outlet of the pump on a household water pressure pump?

Comment: A bit more detail, pictures, diagrams might be helpful. Feel free to [edit] to provide more detail.

Answer (score 2):

No, the pressure tank can really be located anywhere in the system that's convenient. You can also have more than one, if that works out better.

Lacking a sense of what your setup is, let's say your pump output comes in the wall 4 feet high (or you have a shallow well pump in the basement but mounted high for some reason) and you want to put the pressure tank on the floor. That's perfectly fine.